# splitting string is returning full string

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a small script which determines how many words are in a paragraph and then divides the paragraph depending on a certain length. My approach was to split the paragraph using split(), find out how many elements are in the array and then output some of the elements into one paragraph and the rest into another.

```
var para = document.getElementById('aboutParagraph').innerHTML;
var paraElements = para.split();
var paraLength = paraElements.length;

if(paraLength >= 500){

}
console.log(paraElements);
```

when I use this code paraElements is being returned in an array where the first element is the entire string.

Sof for example if the paragraph were "this is a paragraph" paraElements is being returned as: `["this is a paragraph"]`, with a a length of 1. Shouldn't it be `["this", "is", "a", "paragraph"]`?

Comment: probably because you need to pass what you're splitting the string by

Comment: `split()` needs a parameter - the string to split *by*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split. Voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 1):

The **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** method splits a string at a delimiter you specify (can be a literal string, a reference to a string or a regular expression) and then returns an array of all the parts. If you want just one part, you must pass the resulting array an index.

**You are not supplying a delimiter to split on, so you are getting the entire string back.**

```js
var s = "This is my test string";

var result = s.split(/\s+/); // Split everywhere there is one or more spaces

console.log(result);  // The entire resulting array

console.log("There are " + result.length + " words in the string.");

console.log("The first word is: " + result[0]); // Just the first word
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "this is a paragraph";

var ans = str.split(' ');
console.log(ans);
```

You need  to use `split`(' ') with this format. Use ' ', notice space there. You were not passing any parameter by which to split.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the split delimiter for a space. Try this:

```
    var para = document.getElementById('aboutParagraph').innerHTML;
var paraElements = para.split(' ');
var paraLength = paraElements.length;

if(paraLength >= 500){

}
console.log(paraElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `split()` will return an array, if you don't pass in a delimiter as an argument it would encapsulate the whole string into one element of an array.

You can break your words on spaces, but you may want to also consider tabs and newlines.  For that reason, you could use some regex `/\s+/` which will match on any whitespace character.

The `+` is used so that it treats all consecutive whitespace characters as one delimiter. Otherwise a string with two spaces, like `foo  bar` would be treated as three words with one being an empty string `["foo", "", "bar"]` (the plus makes it `["foo", "bar"]` as expected).

```js
var para = document.getElementById('aboutParagraph').innerHTML;
var paraElements = para.split(/\s+/); // <-- need to pass in delimiter to split on
var paraLength = paraElements.length;

if (paraLength >= 500) {}

console.log(paraLength, paraElements);
```

```html
<p id="aboutParagraph">I want to create a small script which determines how many words are in a paragraph and then divides the paragraph depending on a certain length. My approach was to split the paragraph using split(), find out how many elements are in the array and then output some of the elements into one paragraph and the rest into another.</p>
```